# MultiLabel Classification in Keras for moe than 1700 classes

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I have a huge protein dataset. with 9800 features and around 1700 class labels. Each sample can have 4 or 5 of the class label. I have designed the model and performed initial training. I am getting very high accuracy which I know the reason for. 
My question is which optimizer and loss function would be accurate to get good results. Also, can anyone help me with the custom accuracy metric which is proving a bit tricky as it needs to be tensor based.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add some code that you have tried so that the community can help you

Comment: You should be more specific. How does your model look like (how many layers, activation function, loss function optimizer)? You get high accuracy because most of the outputs are 0 and any network can get it really quickly. You should measure rather precision and recall.

Comment: I m using 2 hidden layers first hidden layer has 1500 neurons and second has 500.. activation function I used is LeakyReLU for all the layers except output layer which has sigmoid activation. loss is binary_crossentropy since I read somewhere that it is useful when doing multi-label classification. I found a way to measure accuracy on test data using hamming score. What I need is a little help understanding what changes should I try with my model to get a better performance.

Answer (score 0):

The accuracy is not a good metric for a classification problem if used alone. Check what a [confusion matrix](https://machinelearningmastery.com/confusion-matrix-machine-learning/) is.
First check if you classes are balanced or not. The choice of the loss function heavily depends on this.
Imagine a dataset made of 90 observations with label 0 and 10 with label 1. The classifier which always chooses 0 gets a 90% accuracy even though it is the worst classifier possible.

The optimizer is not very important. Just go for Adam. When your model produces interesting results then you can tune the optimizer.

Comment: okay, Should I also try adding more layers to the model? I have more than 150k samples and I am not getting good accuracy when I am calculating it with the help of hamming score. Also I was trying to add a custom metric to the model.compile but it is a bit difficult to add it since the code has to be written using backend.

Comment: which one would you suggest?